# 'none of the above' check box in a grid auto unchecking other checkboxes in the column, jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

i've got a grid with many rows and two columns. the last row contains 'none of the above' check boxes. when checked i want all other check boxes in the column to become unchecked. when one of the other check boxes in the column gets checked i want the none of the above check box in that column to auto uncheck. here's what i've got... problem is with the second piece of this... i am a noob

```
columnclear : function() {
    // NoneClear -Columngrid
    $(':checkbox[name*="ColumnClear"]').click(function() {
        if ( this.checked === true ) {
            var $table = $(this).closest("table");
            var col = $(this).closest("tr").children().index($(this).closest("td"));
            var index = col+1;
            $table.find("td:nth-child("+index+") input:checkbox") .attr("checked",false);
            $table.find("tr:last td:nth-child("+index+")  input:checkbox").attr("checked", true);
        }
    });
    $(':checkbox[name*!="ColumnClear"]').click(function() {
        if ( this.checked === true ) {
            var $table = $(this).closest("table");
            var col = $(this).closest("tr").children().index($(this).closest("td"));
            var index = col+1;
            $table.find("tr:last td:nth-child("+index+")  input:checkbox").attr("checked", false);
        }
    });
}
```

some of the html:

```
<table summary="Which of the following products/systems does your company own and/or plan to purchase within the next 12 months? (Please select all that apply for each column)" class="mrQuestionTable" style="">
    <tr>
    <td id="Cell.0.0"></td>
    <td id="Cell.1.0" class="mrGridQuestionText" 
    <span class="mrQuestionText" style="color: #000000;;font-weight: bold;">Currently own</span>
    </td>
    <td id="Cell.2.0" class="mrGridQuestionText" 
    <span class="mrQuestionText" style="color: #000000;;font-weight: bold;">Plan to purchase</span>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td id="Cell.0.1" class="mrGridCategoryText" 
    <span class="mrQuestionText" style="">Creative/Design software</span>
    </td>
    <td id="Cell.1.1" 
    <div></div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="_QQ5_Qdesign_Qrating_Cown" id="_Q0_Q0_Q0_C0" class="mrMultiple" style="" value="own"></input>
    </td>
    <td id="Cell.2.1" style="text-Align: Center;vertical-align: Middle;border-color: black;border-style: Solid;border-width: 1px;">
    <div></div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="_QQ5_Qdesign_Qrating_Cplan" id="_Q0_Q0_Q0_C1" class="mrMultiple" style="" value="plan"></input>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td id="Cell.0.21" class="mrGridCategoryText" 
    <span class="mrQuestionText" style="">None of the above</span>
    </td>
    <td id="Cell.1.21" 
    <div></div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="_QQ5_Qnon__ColumnClear1_Qrating_Cown" id="_Q0_Q20_Q0_C0" class="mrMultiple" style="" value="own"></input>
    </td>
    <td id="Cell.2.21" 
    <div></div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="_QQ5_Qnon__ColumnClear1_Qrating_Cplan" id="_Q0_Q20_Q0_C1" class="mrMultiple" style="" value="plan"></input>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: sorry, yes. with the second event piece (from (':checkbox[name*!="ColumnClear"]').click(function() { on) added in the "none of the above" checkboxes (named ColumnClear) become uncheckable. they are supposed to be checkable and when another box in that column becomes checked they are supposed to uncheck.

Comment: so the first event takes care of unchecking all of the non-none of the above checkboxes in the column when none of the above gets checked. the second event is supposed to auto uncheck the none of the above checkboxes when another checkbox in the column becomes checked. it currently does not.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming each checkbox is it its own table and the "clear all" checkboxes have `name="ColumnClear"`, the second block should be:

```
$(':checkbox[name*!="ColumnClear"]').click(function() {
    if ( this.checked === true ) {
        var $table = $(this).closest("table").find(':checkbox[name*="ColumnClear"]').attr("checked", false);
    }
});
```

Comment: this didnt seem to work for me... all checkboxes are in one large table

Comment: added some in to the question above